# Default php debugger in XAMPP or Wamp

Tags: php, debugging, iis, webmatrix

Is there any default debugger in XAMPP or Wamp or we need to insatll it manually. I earlier worked in WebMatrix and found that it didn't debug my PHP code correctly.

Answer (score 0):

[XDebug](http://xdebug.org/) works well.

I believe it should work for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I use the extension Firebug all the time for debugging general stuff.  I've also tried FirePHP for PHP with mixed results.

Comment: @Charliepiga - That's why I said FirePHP!

Answer (score 0):

WebMatrix doesn't include any kind of debugging tools for PHP or ASP.NET. It doesn't integrate with any either. Version 2 includes an extensibility framework for add-on development, so you might potentially find someone creates a debugger in time.